# remove grey horizontal line from top of pdf

Tags: header-footer

I am using a .tex template that I was given.

In the final pdf, there is a grey horizontal line across the top of every page. I would like to remove this, but I'm not sure which line of my file is creating it.

Is there anything obvious that I can try?

Thanks.

---

Update:

I've now looked in the class file for anything that contains the word "head". This section includes all mentions:

```
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{1.96cm}
%\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{-0.54cm}
\setlength{\topmargin}{1mm}
\setlength{\headheight}{1.36cm}
\setlength{\headsep}{1.00cm}
\setlength{\textheight}{20.84cm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{14.5cm}
\setlength{\marginparsep}{1mm}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{3cm}
\setlength{\footskip}{2.36cm}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\MakeUppercase{\thechapter. #1 }}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RO]{\bfseries\rightmark}
\fancyhead[LE]{\bfseries\leftmark}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\addtolength{\headheight}{0.5pt}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
\fancyhead{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
```

Anything obvious is here that I could change?

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe something obvious like `headsepline` or something similar? Really depends on your packages and documentclass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
```

to

```
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
```

So, you sould have

```
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RO]{\bfseries\rightmark}
\fancyhead[LE]{\bfseries\leftmark}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\addtolength{\headheight}{0.5pt}
```